# Executing Shell (bash) from PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Does anyone know how to execute a shell script from a PL/SQL procedure or function? Let's say the shell script is '/usr/bin/bash/convert.sh'.

Comment: Execute a shell script from a PL/SQL procedure: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_execute_shell_script_plsql_procedure.htm (hope this help). If not,  can you provide more info ?

Comment: Hi Luan,

Thanks for the link, though I haven't tried that yet. Do you have any working samples for the approach in the link?

I have created a shell script to convert pdf to ps(post script), then the input filepath will be passed from a PL/SQL procedure/function. 
I've been thinking if the shell script can be directly invoked from pl/sql.

Do you have any other thoughts on how to achieve this one?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: DBMS.SCHEDULER is straightforward. Try this link for an example https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9526591800346357583

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an external job for that.

[Techniques for External Jobs](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/scheduse.htm#CIAJCFHE)

First, you need to create a credential, with the OS user and password in whose name the job will run:

```
begin
  dbms_scheduler.create_credential
  (
    credential_name => 'my_credential',
    username        => 'oracle',
    password        => 'Oracle123'
  );
end;
/
```

After that you can use this credential when creating an external job. For example calling your convert script with 2 arguments (input and output file)

```
begin
  dbms_scheduler.create_job
  (
    job_name             => 'convert_job',
    job_type             => 'executable',
    number_of_arguments  => 2,
    job_action           => '/usr/bin/bash/convert.sh',
    auto_drop            => true,
    credential_name      => 'my_credential'
  );

  dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('convert_job', 1, '/home/oracle/file.in');
  dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('convert_job', 2, '/home/oracle/file.out');

  dbms_scheduler.enable('convert_job');
end;
/
```